# How to Unmount / Remove Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have gone through many sites where they explain how we can create/mount new engine OR convert existing Rails App to engine.
But didn't found any link where they have explained about how to unmount Or remove engine.

I am working with rails version 3.2.2.

can any one help me out with this??

Comment: For now i have
Remove reference for the Engine from Gemfile.
Remove routes related to engine fro routes.rb
Down all the migration related to engine.
Remove the engine from lib/engines.
It completely removes engine from our rails app.

but..It there any better way to do so..??

Answer (score 1):

Once you remove the engine from your `Gemfile` , the engine is unmounted/removed from your main application.

Rest all the references are just you manually added to your main application dependent on Engines, you would have to remove them by self.
Like in routes.rb , the mounting is optional and thus you have to remove it by self. 
In lib/engines you placed the engine , it can be anywhere on your system or remote link like github. Thus, you would have to remove these additional references yourself... Not sure about migrations if they can be directly un-installed or not..